# Auto scroll down a textarea after refreshing a page

Tags: php, html

I have a script that shows a log of a program, I've tried to add `header("refresh: 5;url=wget_log.php#bottomOfPage");` but it still won't scroll down to the bottom of the textarea. Here's my script:

```
<?php
header("refresh: 5;url=wget_log.php#bottomOfPage");
include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();
echo " Wget log :<br>";
echo "<textarea name=\"bottomOfPage\" rows=\"30\" cols=\"90\" readonly style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 7pt;\" >";
$datalines = file ("wget.log");
foreach ($datalines as $zz) {
echo $zz; }
echo "</textarea></div>";
foot();
echo '

</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

Here's the webpage looks like, sorry I'm still not allowed to show images directly on stackoverflow so I'm just gonna give you the link to the image: http://s22.postimg.org/cgap9i8kh/image.jpg

@**Magictallguy** I modified my script to be like this:

```
<?php
header("refresh: 5;url=wget_log.php#bottomOfPage");
include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();
echo " Wget log :<br>";
echo "<textarea name=\"text-info\" rows=\"30\" cols=\"90\" readonly style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 7pt;\" >";
$datalines = file ("wget.log");
foreach ($datalines as $zz) {
echo $zz; }
echo "<span id=\"bottomOfPage\">&nbsp;</span>"
echo "</textarea></div>";
foot();
echo '

</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

but it still won't scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id="bottomOfPage"` somewhere at the bottom of the page

Or, more precisely, add `<span id='bottomOfPage'>&nbsp;</span>` just before your `</textarea>` tag

Comment: I tried `echo "<textarea name=\"text-info\" id=\"bottomOfPage\" rows=\"30\" cols=\"90\" readonly style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 7pt;\" >";` but still doesn't work

Comment: Please see my updated post, it still doesn't want to scroll down